# Does Tor affect ping for online games?

Tags: performance

Does Tor affect ping for online games? The servers to which I usually connect are in Europe. Is there a way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the browser bundle it only sends the data that goes in\out of the firefox portable browser that's included with the bundle through tor.
You say you play BF4 and that ping is not affected - it should not affect BF4 at all - since that traffic is not routed through tor.

If you want to relay all traffic then you need transparent proxying or a 'middlebox' routing everything, which is not recommended on a windows OS machine, because of leaking.

Battlefield 4 is windows only, and also UDP communication is not supported through tor either, so playing games over tor like this makes no sense.

In regards of your youtube video question - it shows them with html5 video player instead of flash.

Comment: well I am running Vidalia as a Tor client only, and it is currently connected to the TOR network. so this configuration does not tunnel all the PC's traffic through TOR network?

Comment: NO it doesn't, for that i will need a transparent proxy, as you said, like Tallow. thanks :).
can you direct me to more onfo regarding leakage over transparent proxy? Tallow gave one example but i feel there is more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your latency would go up to unplayable levels. Its a bad idea to play games with Tor. A VPN that connects from a european country would be a better choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Tor, your traffic not only goes through the internet routers but among them passes at least 3 other routers (onion routers) these ones have to decrypt part of the information and forward it, which would cause additional time too, so the answer is **yes**.

Tor exit nodes are used by many users at the time and usually their bandwidth is slow.

But Tor works only over TCP protocol so UDP packets don't go over Tor and as far as I know, most online games for which the ping matters use UDP because TCP is not suitable for them. You may have heard about the lag (lost packets) that is because UDP.

Comment: I tried and played few rounds of BF4.... the pings were not affected at all, is that normal? does it mean TOR is not working properly?
on a side note I noticed that YouTube is working normally too while TOR is Connected AND using the TOR browser (default settings). reference to TOR download page: "...The lack of plugins means that Youtube videos are blocked by default, but Youtube does provide an experimental opt-in feature that works for some videos."

Comment: About youtube: 

youtube uses for streaming TCP so it goes over Tor, i´ve captured many times my traffic, i know that for sure.  


About Bf 4:

It seems that the game uses multiples TCP and UDP ports but the main ones are the UDP so the TCP traffic could go through Tor but the
UDP no. [check this link](https://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/es/forum/threadview/2955064767505704337/)

if you want to send the tcp packets through Tor you should find a way to do it because by default these traffic doesn't go through tor.